# Passport JWT: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined in MEAN

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, passport.js

im building an CMS using express and angular 5
i try to set passport JWT authentication but i keep getting error if i try to access a protected route on the back end.

i loged the **jwt_payload** and there is no **user** there.
so i though there is problem with the Header i sending, but it looks fine, the "authorization" header contains the token.

Im really helpless

this is my setup:

**passport strategy**

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport){
let opts = {};

opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
opts.passReqToCallback = true;

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    User.getUserById(jwt_payload.user._id, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
            return done(err, false);
        }

        if(user){
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
}));
}
```

**The route**

```
// Profile
router.post('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res, next) => {
res.json({user: req.user});
});
```

**And the angular service**

```
getProfile(){
let headers = new Headers();
this.loadToken();
headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
console.log(headers)
return this.http.get(API_URL + '/users/profile', {headers : headers})
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

**Authenticate/Login**

```
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
const username = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;

User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
if(err) throw err;
if(!user){
  return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
}

User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
  if(err) throw err;
  if(isMatch){

    const token = jwt.sign({user}, config.secret, {
      expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
    });

    res.json({
      success: true,
      token: 'JWT '+ token,
      user: {
        id: user._id,
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
        firstname: user.firstname,
        lastname: user.lastname,
        role: user.role
      }
    });
  } else {
    return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Wrong password'});
  }
});
});
});
```

thats the jwt_payload from the req

```
  headers:
 { host: 'localhost:8080',
 connection: 'keep-alive',
 'content-length': '0',
 authorization: 'JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7Il9pZCI6IjVhNWUxYzhlYTI3OWJiMDAyMGZmM2Q5NCIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJlbWFpbCI6Im1vcm96LmEyNEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJmaXJzdG5hbWUiOiJBbGV4IiwibGFzdG5hbWUiOiJNb3JveiIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiJDJhJDEwJEdXdk5uVEFtRVVjVEY5SDdtaHg4aE8waHFUaVhqU1oycVVUZkFXTzdGOEE5amZDNXFXT015IiwiX192IjowLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4ifSwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MTIzNDY5LCJleHAiOjE1MTY3MjgyNjl9.X7iVs6iGrL1NbSfxxNAUBOXV4M5fITFPvcoRzQ6NPnU',
 'postman-token': 'ac9c9f81-3e51-f7af-2203-7022d13359cf',
 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
 origin: 'chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop',
 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36',
 'content-type': 'application/json',
 accept: '*/*',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
 'accept-language': 'he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' },
 rawHeaders:
 [ 'Host',
 'localhost:8080',
 'Connection',
 'keep-alive',
 'Content-Length',
 '0',
 'Authorization',
 'JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7Il9pZCI6IjVhNWUxYzhlYTI3OWJiMDAyMGZmM2Q5NCIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJlbWFpbCI6Im1vcm96LmEyNEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJmaXJzdG5hbWUiOiJBbGV4IiwibGFzdG5hbWUiOiJNb3JveiIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiJDJhJDEwJEdXdk5uVEFtRVVjVEY5SDdtaHg4aE8waHFUaVhqU1oycVVUZkFXTzdGOEE5amZDNXFXT015IiwiX192IjowLCJyb2xlIjoiYWRtaW4ifSwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MTIzNDY5LCJleHAiOjE1MTY3MjgyNjl9.X7iVs6iGrL1NbSfxxNAUBOXV4M5fITFPvcoRzQ6NPnU',
 'Postman-Token',
 'ac9c9f81-3e51-f7af-2203-7022d13359cf',
 'Cache-Control',
 'no-cache',
 'Origin',
 'chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop',
 'User-Agent',
 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36',
 'Content-Type',
 'application/json',
 'Accept',
 '*/*',
 'Accept-Encoding',
 'gzip, deflate, br',
 'Accept-Language',
 'he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' ]
```

Comment: What's your `jwt_payload` look like?

Comment: How are you signing your payload? did you check the route that's responsible for creating the JWT token? did you log it after it's creation? 
I don't see that code posted in your question, you should add it.
Also from my personal mistakes.. check that your header is the one passport expects-  
 “Authorization”:”bearer TOKEN_STRING”.

Comment: added jwt_payload and the Authenticate

Answer (score 1):

inside :

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    User.getUserById(jwt_payload.user._id, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
            return done(err, false);
        }

        if(user){
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
}));
```

change:

```
 User.getUserById(jwt_payload._id, (err, user) => {
```

reason:

```
console.log(jwt_payload.user._id)
```

which is undefined

but

```
console.log(jwt_payload._id)
```

will give you user id.

This resolved my issue. hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(jwt_payload));
```

And check whether that there is a property called `_id`.